# Twitter Bootstrap Template Section Issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to HTML, CSS and Javascript. I've been learning Twitter Bootstrap since a few days. I've redone a basic homepage of this [website](https://simplestepscode.com/) using Twitter Bootstrap.

For the first-timer, I think I've done a decent job. But could you please give me the feedback or correct the code to get the homepage exactly similar to the web page aforementioned.

The web page is utilizing min-width (mobile-first approach) for media queries. I've used to max-width to redo it.

I struggled a bit while making the second section (where all the logo of the famous brands are) of the web page.

And I've used a text-only logo.

Could you please correct me or guide me in further building the web page (just the homepage).

Thank you.

Please review the web page over here at [Codepen](http://codepen.io/sharmaamit/pen/XpjQwO).
                    
                  
                    My material has been featured, mentioned, or used by:

```
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4">
                    <img class="featured_logos wdd" alt="WebdesignerDepot" src="https://placehold.it/260x68"></div>
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                      <img class="featured_logos wdd" alt="WebdesignerDepot" src="https://placehold.it/260x68"></div>
                      <div class="col-md-4">
                        <img class="featured_logos wdd" alt="WebdesignerDepot" src="https://placehold.it/260x68"></div>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a good example of an area where you would not want to use columns or separate rows. To get that transition of them popping down into place when they run out of room you just need to have them all lined up correctly. I recommend something like this:

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
       <img class="featured_logos wdd" alt="WebdesignerDepot" src="https://placehold.it/260x68">
       <img class="featured_logos wdd" alt="WebdesignerDepot" src="https://placehold.it/260x68">
       <img class="featured_logos wdd" alt="WebdesignerDepot" src="https://placehold.it/260x68">
       <img class="featured_logos wdd" alt="WebdesignerDepot" src="https://placehold.it/260x68">
       <img class="featured_logos wdd" alt="WebdesignerDepot" src="https://placehold.it/260x68">
       <img class="featured_logos wdd" alt="WebdesignerDepot" src="https://placehold.it/260x68">
       <img class="featured_logos wdd" alt="WebdesignerDepot" src="https://placehold.it/260x68">
       <img class="featured_logos wdd" alt="WebdesignerDepot" src="https://placehold.it/260x68">
    </div>
 </div>

.featured_logos {
    margin: 10px 25px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 60%;
    height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Benneb10. It worked. How did you manage to get five logos in the top row and three in the bottom row? That's how they're stacking up when viewed on Desktop.

Comment: Hey @Amitsharma that's just how it works out. The container has a fixed width of 1170px, and the row and col-xs-12 all take up 100% of this size. Each of the logos are 152px wide with a margin of 25px on each side. That makes them each about 202px. 202 X 5 = 1010. The sixth logo is forced to a new line because it doesn't have enough room on the line above.

Comment: That explains it, @Benneb10. Thank you.